# Accessing View from Controller during cucumber test

Tags: grails, cucumber, grails-controller

I have a controller `UserController`, this controller has the `register()` method which uses a service to register a user and then renders output.

I'm using the Grails Cucumber plugin and it creates a UserController object, sets params, and calls `userControllerObj.register()`

in the "Then" part of the cucumber test I can call `userController.response.contentAsString()` and that will be whatever text I wrote in the UserController by `render "some text here"`.

However if I in the UserController register method change the render from rendering a String to rendering a page: `render(view: "registrationOK")` I am unable to get any output:

`userController.response` is a `GrailsMockHttpServletResponse`

`userController.response.getText returns` an empty string

`userController.response.contentAsString` returns an empty String

`userController.response.contentType` returns text/html;charset=utf-8

`userController.response.contentLength` returns 0

`userController.modelAndView.view` returns null

Comment: userController.register();
println response.text;